# Angular page to node.js server socket connection

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I have a problem with this.

This is the code in my node.js server:

```
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var express    = require('express');
var http       = require('http').Server(app);
var io         = require('socket.io')(http);
var app        = express();

......    

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.emit('welcome', { message: 'Welcome!', id: socket.id });

    socket.on('i am client', console.log);
});

app.listen(port);
```

And my angular page:

```
var modulo_angular = angular.module('app', ['btford.socket-io', 'ngRoute']);
modulo_angular.factory('socket', function (socketFactory) {
    var myIoSocket = io.connect('http://myurl:8000/');
    var mySocket = socketFactory({
        ioSocket: myIoSocket
    });
   return mySocket;
});

modulo_angular.controller("appCtrl",['factoryController', 'socket',controladorSecundario]);
```

The error I get is:

```
GET http://myurl:8000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1435131076378-14 404 (Not Found)
```

If I use 'http://localhost' instead an url, I get ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED. I am in the same network, connected through a vpn and ports are opened. Do I need something else in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the browser trying to get `http://myurl:8000/socket.io/` which is missing. I believe this is due to your server setup.

Try this:

```
var port = 8000;
var app = express();
var server = app.listen(port); // start the server
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server); // start socketIO
```

Comment: I think port is ok. (Sorry I forgot to add 'var port    = 8000;'), because I can access to my webpage which is served by my node.js server.

Comment: By saying "this is due to your server setup" I didn't mean the port. I meant setting up express with socketIo is not correct. Try opening `http://myurl:8000/socket.io/` in your browser

Comment: I get {"code":0,"message":"Transport unknown"}. I guess you are right. How can I check my server setup?

Comment: Try replacing the first 5 lines in your node.js code with the lines in the answer.

Comment: same problem. Anyway, I have to add bodyParser and require('express') line to avoid errors when I run the server. I installed socket.io through npm and I didn't see any error in log.

Comment: I think something wans't refreshed properly. Now the user connect to my server. Thank you.